# How do I retrieve information from database for my C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I am currently developing a C# Windows Form Application.

Now I am trying to use a SQL Command to retrieve information from the database to fill in the information that I need to have in my Application.

A sample query would be "select * from Member"

In the member table there would be variables like name, location, etc etc.

How do I code it in my application such that i can fill up my variables with the information from the database?

My code for the method would be

```
private Panel createNotificationPanel(String name, String location, String imageExtension, String alertType, String memberid)
    {

    }
```

I have already created a member class which includes all the set and get method for all this values

and currently what I have done so far is :

```
String connectionString =         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection2"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from alert);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(dataset, "authenticate");
        conn.Close();


        int respond = (int)dataset.Tables["authenticate"].Rows[0]["respond"];

if (respond == 1)
        {
            //to fill in here
        }
```

after retrieving the information I am going to add it to a list as follow

```
List.Add(new MemberAlert("name", "location", "type", "memberID", "imageExtension"));
```

so i am wondering how do i replace the information inside with the one in the database
I am not sure of how do I proceed from here. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Unless you're using .NET 2.0, i recommend that you stay away from DataSet/DataTable and instead use Entity Framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection connection = 
    new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
        "select * from alert", connection);
    adapter.Fill(dataset, "authenticate");
}

// Load Data from the DataSet into the ListView
private void LoadList()
{
    // Get the table from the data set
    DataTable dtable = dataset.Tables["authenticate"];

    // Clear the ListView control
    listView1.Items.Clear();

    // Display items in the ListView control
    for (int i = 0; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        DataRow drow = dtable.Rows[i];

        // Define the list items
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["name"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add (drow["location"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add (drow["type"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add (drow["memberID"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add (drow["imageExtension"].ToString());

        // Add the list items to the ListView
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

if you need to create list out of dataset table. you can iterate rows as above and create list items inside the loop and add them to list.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, but that is currently what I have done so far as mentioned in my post, what I meant is how do I fill the variable with the information from database that I have retrieved?

Comment: @Thomas DataTable dt = dataset.Tables[0]; - Edit: you've already done that when you assign a value to the respond integer, I dont know what you mean.

Comment: Hi im sorry as i'm pretty new to programming. what i meant was since i need to retrieve the name,location,etc information from the database, after executing the sql command, how do I place the information into my variable? or simply , aft the data is added to the dataset how do i display it out?

Comment: Sorry I see what you mean, try this:DataTable dt = dataset.Tables[0]; foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {List.Add(new MemberAlert(dr[columnIndex],dr[columnIndex],etc )); }

Comment: thank you all very much. I am able to retrieve the information. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can load your data without having to fill an intermediate `DataSet` by using [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) and [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx).  So something like the following:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select respond from alert";
var respond = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (respond != null && (int)respond == 1)
{
   //... execute your command to select from Member here
}
```

Then, inside your `if` use `ExecuteReader`, and load the values directly from the [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx):

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Member";

using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        list.Add(new MemberAlert
            {
                Name = reader.GetString(0),
                // load other properties from reader
            });
    }
}
```