# Save Image to word of HTML reference

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic, ms-word

I export data from my database to word in HTML format from my web application, which works fine for me , i have inserted image into record,
the document displays the image also , all works fine for me except when i save that file and send to someone else .. ms word will not find link to that image

Is there anyway to save that image on the document so path issues will not raise

Here is my code : StrTitle contains all the HTML including Image links as well

```
  string strBody = "<html>" +
            "<body>" + strTitle +
            "</body>" +
            "</html>";
        string fileName = "Policies.doc";
        //object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        // You can add whatever you want to add as the HTML and it will be generated as Ms Word docs
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.Write(strBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your html `img` tag with the image data encoded with base64. This way the image data is contained in the html document it self.

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />`

Comment: Couldn't get this to work.  Any ideas?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399831/how-to-write-an-image-to-an-html-word-document

Answer (score 0):

You images are probably only available via filesystem (i.e. their `src` starts with `file`).

There are a few ways

1. Make the image available via the internet: make sure their `src` starts with `http` and that they are hosted on a web server visible to the downloader (for example, the same server from which they are dowonloading the image)
2. Use a library, for example [see NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages?q=word)
3. You can inline the images as [@DevZer0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17082867/7028) suggests.

Based on experience

1. Is the simplest to implement but has some annoyances (the server needs to be available to the user)
2. Is probably the best way if you do a lot of Word or Office files manipulation.
3. Can be done and it would solve the problem, although you wouldn't have a full library to support further use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since every picture, table is of type shape in Word/Excel/Powerpoint, you could simply add with your program an AlternativeText to your picture, which would actually save a URL of the download URL and when you open, it will retrieve its URL and replace it.

```
foreach (NetOffice.WordApi.InlineShape s in docWord.InlineShapes)
{
    if (s.Type==NetOffice.WordApi.Enums.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture &&  s.AlternativeText.Contains("|"))
    {
          s.AlternativeText=<your website URL to download the picture>;
    }
}
```

This would be the C# approach, but would require more time for the picture. If you write a small software for it, which replaces all pictures which contain a **s.AlternativeText**, you could replace a lot of pictures at same time.

```
NetOffice.WordApi.InlineShape i=appWord.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(s.AlternativeText, false, true);
```

It will look for the picture at that location.

You can do that for your whole document with the 1 loop I wrote you. Means, if it is a picture and contains some AlternativeText, then inside you loop you use the AddPicture function.

Edit: Anoter solution, would be to set a hyperlink to your picture, which would actually go to a FTP server where the picture is located and when you click on the picture, it will open it, means he can replace it by himself(bad, if you have 200 pictures in your document)

Edit according Clipboard:

```
 string html = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
 File.WriteAllText(temporaryFilePath, html);
 NetOffice.WordApi.InlineShape i=appWord.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(temporaryFilePath, false, true);
```

The Clipboard in Word is capable to transform a given HTML and when you paste it to transform that table or picture into Word. This works too for Excel, but doesn't for Powerpoint. You could do something like that for your pictures and drag and drop from your database.
[image]

Comment: Actually this method failed , because its just showing me the HTML Text , but if i open the file through notepad it shows me the HTML . 
Can anyone know how to do this work using interop.word ..
i have used interop.word when i just have to replace the data , i did that by adding bookmarks on the word template 
but here i need to show a large data on word document .. can anyone help me regarding that

Comment: Actually this method doesn't fail. I can without any problem visualize a table that has been created by a HTML code in Word. What I maybe forgot to mention was to use the Clipboard. Check at my Edited post

Comment: Actually i was talking about my post , i want to do this work by using interop.word

Comment: Sorry about that  , Please can u tell me the way how i can export my database data to word template

Comment: For exporting your data in C#, find here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017843/how-do-i-retrieve-information-from-database-for-my-c-sharp-windows-form-applicat how to do it. Since you can retrieve the data, now in your template word, you simply need to replace every picture. If you have an existing picture assign it a AlternativeText in that case, later if you retrieve your database information with the link, the AlternativeText has that link and with your tool, you can automatically replace the picture and take the picture from your database URL.

Comment: by replacing adding bookmarks on the word template , i know how to do that .. but what if i dont know how many images are there in database .. is there anyway not to replace but show all the images and text i am retrieving from database on the word template  , without replacing tags and adding bookmarks

Comment: Yes, what you should do, is to create an Add-In, which would show you all the images from your database.

Comment: @OsamaKhalid check for the picture I added. You could do something like that but for Word. It's done with an Add-In.

Answer (score 0):

Use a word document creation library if you really want to have flexibility in creating doc or docx type files. Like all other popular document formats, the structure needs to be accurate enough for the program that opens up the documents. Like you obviously cannot create a PDF file just by setting content type "application/PDF", if your content is not in a structure that PDF reader expects. Content type would just make the browser identify the extension (incorrectly in this case) and download it as a PDF, but its actually simple text. Same goes for MS word or any other format that requires a particular document structure to be parsed and displyed properly.