# How to write an image to an HTML Document set to open in Word

Tags: html, ms-word

I am attempting to write an image to an HTML Document that will open in Word from C#.  Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17082867, it seems like I should be able to just write an image tax with the src set to the image data:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

However, my file is not working.  Word opens and shows a red "X" box with the following message:

> The linked image cannot be displayed.  The file may have be moved,
>   renamed, or deleted.  Verify that the link points to the correct file
>   and location.

Here is my html, saved as a .docx extension:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      body { font-family: Calibri, Tahoma; }
      h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 { font-weight: normal; }
    </style>   </head>   \
  <body>
    <h3>Here is the image:</h3>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="" />      
  </body> 
</html>
```

I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: What's an HTML Word document? I know what an HTML document is, and I know what a Word document is, but a HTML Word document is new to me.

Comment: @j08691 What I am referring to is an html document that is written from, in this case, C#, but is saved with a .doc/.docx extension so that it opens in Word.  I'm not sure what the right nomenclature is for that.

Comment: OK, I think your edits have clarified it. Thanks.

Comment: Repeated code: data:image/png;base64,data:image/png;base64,

Comment: @jeff Oops.  Thanks... I was trying to overwrite a much longer png with a smaller one for this post and left that in.  That's not the issue, though.